# How to capture live running traces from MSO7104B oscilloscope with the help of MATLAB without any delay?

Tags: matlab, oscilloscope, tracesource

% Create instrument object for Agilent oscilloscope
`oscilloscope = visa('agilent', 'GPIB0::9::INSTR');` % Change the VISA address as per your oscilloscope configuration
% Set communication parameters

```
set(oscilloscope, 'InputBufferSize', 1024);
set(oscilloscope, 'Timeout', 10);
%
```

Open communication with the oscilloscope
`fopen(oscilloscope);` % Configure oscilloscope settings

```
fprintf(oscilloscope, ':WAVEFORM:FORMAT BYTE'); % Set waveform format to BYTE
fprintf(oscilloscope, ':WAVEFORM:UNIFORM:ENABLE 1'); % Enable uniform waveform data
fprintf(oscilloscope, ':WAVEFORM:POINTS 10000'); % Set the number of points to capture
fprintf(oscilloscope, ':WAVEFORM:SOURCE CH1'); % Select the waveform source (e.g., Channel 1)
fprintf(oscilloscope, ':WAVEFORM:DATA?'); % Request waveform data
%
```

Read and process the waveform data continuously

```
isCapturing = true;
while isCapturing
%
```

Read waveform data

```
 waveformData = binblockread(oscilloscope, 'int16'); % Read waveform data as int16
    waveformData = waveformData'; % Transpose the data for easier processing
%
```

Perform processing or analysis on the waveformData
% Example: Calculate the maximum value of the captured waveform
`maxValue = max(waveformData);`% Plot the captured waveform in real-time

```
 plot(waveformData);
    drawnow;
%
```

Check for an exit condition (e.g., press a key to stop capturing)

```
if kbhit % Check if a key is pressed
        isCapturing = false;
    end
end
```

% Close communication with the oscilloscope
`fclose(oscilloscope);` % Clean up the instrument object

```
delete(oscilloscope);
clear oscilloscope;
```

I tried various codes and only this code suited me to an extent. I need to capture live running traces without any delay or pause with the help of MATLAB